# How to Prevent Direct URL Access in strongloop?

Tags: node.js, access-token, loopbackjs, strongloop

How to redirect users to login page when users try to access without login using direct URL.

I have completed a token based authentication, after user login I got token, so I will maintain same token for further request. But I tried direct url without login, page is loading. I want to allow access only after user login.

Please refer this link https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-access-control. I have downloaded this application and I tried the direct url without login **(that is http://localhost:3000/projects)**, page is loading. Here I want to redirect login page. Please suggest any sample application.

**I am not using AngularSDK**

Comment: please show us some sample code and/or what you have tried so far

Comment: @Noam Hacker  I have added more details please look